# How to style Microsoft PowerBI IFrame?

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm using the following libraries:

```
import { PowerBIEmbed } from 'powerbi-client-react';
import { models } from 'powerbi-client';
```

And I would like to remove the background, and the spacing between the "boards" and the navigation tab at the bottom.

I tried to use a custom className, but it didn't work, the classes that are inside are the ones that come in the IFrame itself.

```
const CustomPage = styled(Page)`
  margin-top: 1rem;

  .powerbi-embed-container {
    width: 100%;

    iframe {
      border: none !important;

      .backgroundContainer,
      .visualBackgroundContainer,
      .outspaceContainer {
        background-color: transparent !important;
      }

      .embeddedLandingRootContentLogoHidden {
        height: 90% !important;
      }
    }
  }
`;


 <CustomPage>
        <PowerBIEmbed
          cssClassName="powerbi-embed-container"
          embedConfig={{
            type: 'report', // Supported types: report, dashboard, tile, visual and qna
            id: '',
            embedUrl: '',
            accessToken: '',
            tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
            settings: {
              layoutType: models.LayoutType.Custom,
            },
          }}
          eventHandlers={
            new Map([
              ['loaded', function () {console.log('Report loaded');}],
              ['rendered', function () {console.log('Report rendered');}],
              ['error', function (event) {console.log(event.detail);}]
            ])
          }
          getEmbeddedComponent={(embeddedReport) => {
            window.report = embeddedReport;
          }}
        />
      </CustomPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the changes you want can be achieved by updating the embed configuration object.

In your embed configuration object,you can use customLayout to change the alignment of visuals:

```
customLayout: {
    ...
    pagesLayout: {
        "ReportSection1": {
            defaultLayout: {
                displayState: {
                    mode: models.VisualContainerDisplayMode.Hidden
                }
            },
            visualsLayout: {
                "VisualContainer1": {
                    x: 1,
                    y: 1,
                    z: 1,
                    width: 400,
                    height: 300,
                    displayState: {
                        mode: models.VisualContainerDisplayMode.Visible
                    }
                },
                "VisualContainer2": {
                    displayState: {
                        mode: models.VisualContainerDisplayMode.Visible
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update pageNavigation and filter pane visibility to false to hide them and set background to transparent:

```
 let config = {
        ...
        settings: {
            background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
            panes: {
                filters: {
                    visible: false
                },
                pageNavigation: {
                    visible: false
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/configure-report-settings

https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/custom-layout

If you want to explore all Power BI APIs, you can checkout: [Microsoft Power BI Embedded Analytics Playground](https://playground.powerbi.com/dev-sandbox)